# Distributing Modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given the following function, `f`:

`f (a b c d e) = (5*a + 4*b + 3*c + 2*b + 1*a) modulo 11`

How can I distribute the modulo operation?

In short, How can I compute `f` without computing `(5*a + 4*b + 3*c + 2*b + 1*a)` first, and then mod-ing by 11.

Comment: I think you can do (a+b) mod c =[(a mod c)+(b mod c) ] mod c

Comment: Yes you can, but I assume you mean multiplying and adding the *right-hand* side.

Comment: Yes - updated my question per your point, @Oiler!

Comment: You can distribute the modulo over all terms, but there will be no simplification. On the opposite, you'll have to take five moduli (plus a final one) instead of a single.

Comment: Care to post as answer, Yves?